# É possível adicionar uma condicional às opções de uma combobox? VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, combobox

0

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário pelo UserForm do VBA e gostaria de gerar uma condicional nele.

Tenho duas ComboBox. A primeira permite escolher entre apenas dois casos, o A e o B. Gostaria que a segunda apresentasse um set de opções diferentes dependendo da escolha do usuário da primeira comboBox, A ou B.

Exemplo: Caso o usuário escolha A na comboBox 1, a comboBox 2 pode ser preenchida com os numeros de 1 a 10. Caso ele escolha B na comboBox 1, a comboBox 2 pode ser preenchida com os numeros de 20 a 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola Leandro segue o exemplo. Mas gostaria de avisa-lo que este é um problema simples e peço que tome um pouco mais de tempo procurando pela solução. **É muito provavel que esta solução/pergunta seja fechada em detrimento a ser um codigo onde não adc. a comunidade. (fique aqui claro que não falo pela Stackoverflow)** Espero que entenda que não quero apontar e nem criticar ninguem, somente um aviso.

No mais desejo lhe sorte!

```
Private Sub cmb_Set01_Change()
    cmb_Set02.Clear

    If cmb_Set01.Value = "A" Then
        cmb_Set02.AddItem "1"
        cmb_Set02.AddItem "2"
        cmb_Set02.AddItem "3"
        cmb_Set02.AddItem "4"
        cmb_Set02.AddItem "5"
    ElseIf cmb_Set01.Value = "B" Then
        cmb_Set02.AddItem "6"
        cmb_Set02.AddItem "7"
        cmb_Set02.AddItem "8"
        cmb_Set02.AddItem "9"
        cmb_Set02.AddItem "10"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    cmb_Set01.AddItem "A"
    cmb_Set01.AddItem "B"

End Sub
```